# Constructor on type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I'm trying to create an instance of HttpPostedFile with

```
var obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(
    typeof(HttpPostedFile), 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new object[] { },
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
);
```

but I'm getting the error 'Constructor on type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' not found.'.

Is there another way to create an instance of HttpPostedFile or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use `System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase` instead.  This has the same methods as `HttpPostedFile` but is designed for sub-classing.  You can then use `HttpPostedFileWrapper`to pass in a real `HttpPostedFile` to a method expecting an `HttpPostedFileBase`.

These extra classes are in the System.Web.Abstractions assembly. ASP.NET MVC makes use of this (and other abstractions in the same assembly) to make unit testing easier. See [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I've just had the same problem and solved it using Moq as follows

```
var postedfile = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
postedfile.Setup(f => f.ContentLength).Returns(8192);
postedfile.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("myfile.txt");
postedfile.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(new MemoryStream(8192));
myObject.HttpPostedFile = postedfile.Object;
```

Answer (score 3):

[HttpPostedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) has an internal constructor that takes 3 arguments and that is not intended to be called from your code:

```
internal HttpPostedFile(string filename, string contentType, HttpInputStream stream)
```

In order to instantiate this class you will need to pass a filename, a content type and a `HttpInputStream` instance which is a type that is also internal so the only way to instantiate it is through reflection.

Comment: And how would you instantiate it with reflection because I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

HttpPostedFile does not expose public constructors, it's available with the file upload control.

I think you should use some other class, so what exactly are you trying to do with the HttpPostedFile?